# How to request for tracks Using the SoundCloud SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, sdk, soundcloud

I Have read the soundcloud documentation, It doesn't say much on searching for a track on  soundcloud. So far in my app i can get, list and search all track of a user but i cant search all of soundcloud tracks(tracks by all soundcloud users).

Thou i have seen this but don't know how to use it:

```
$ curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
```

I got the above from

**http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks**

Please how do i use this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the /tracks endpoint with the q & other parameters.

Example search:

Format JSON / Search for "Berlin" / Genres: Techno

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOURCLIENTID&q=berlin&format=json&genres=techno
```